# Nextjs dynamic pages based on backend return

Tags: reactjs, next.js

There are many examples how to create dynamic pages in nextjs.

```
server.get('/p/:id', (req, res) => {
      const actualPage = '/post';
      const queryParams = { title: req.params.id };
      app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams);
    });
```

All the examples or answers require first part to tell nextjs which page is required to render like /p

However, I could not find any example or questions about how to create pages from api return.

For example, When I request to server with url /my-favorite-fruit.
Api would return like this

```
{
  component: 'PineApple'
}
```

Then I would like to render PineApple component as page.

Anyone tried this one?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass an object containing the route component and the url as `actualePage`:

```
const actualPage = {
    page: ‘/route/file/path/relative/to/pages/folder/‘,
    path: ‘/url/to/show/,j
}

server.get('/p/:id', (req, res) => {
      const actualPage = '/post';
      const queryParams = { title: req.params.id };
      app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams);
    });
```

Then in the route component, eg. `Fruit`, you have to render the `Pineapple` component

Comment: I do not want to have /p